# How to get text file content to table using awk,sed,grep or cut in linux terminal prompt

Tags: awk, sed, grep, cut

```
cat raw.txt

Name country IP Cost  
sam us 10.10.10.10 $250  
jack India 10.10.10.12 $190  
joy Australia 10.10.10.13 $230  
christ canada 10.10.10.15 $190  
jackson africa 10.10.10.20 $230
```

I need to output like a table list four column and four row, i.e Name Country IP Cost

http://res.cloudinary.com/dzy8bgton/image/upload/v1413617325/Screenshot_from_2014-10-18_12_35_11_h6wjsu.png

please anyone can help me out.

Comment: You can read it using `R`  and using `xtable` package to generate latex code. http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xtable/vignettes/xtableGallery.pdf

Comment: Where do you want to output it? In the shell or somewhere else?

Comment: I want like table in shell promnt only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an old school answer :-)

```
#!/bin/sh
# use tbl|nroff to make an ASCII table
# use sed to change multiple spaces into a  single tab for tbl(1)
sed 's/  */\t/g' < raw.txt | awk '
BEGIN {
    print ".TS" # beginning of table
    print "allbox;" # allbox format
    print "c s s s" # Table name format - centered and spanning 4 columns
    print "lb lb lb lb" # bold column headers
    print "l l l l." # table with 4 left justified columns. "." means repeat for next line
    print "My Table" # Table name
}
{print} # print each line of 4 values
END {
    print ".TE" # end of table
}' | tbl | nroff -Tdumb
```

which generates

```
┌─────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                My Table                 │
├────────┬───────────┬─────────────┬──────┤
│Name    │ country   │ IP          │ Cost │
├────────┼───────────┼─────────────┼──────┤
│sam     │ us        │ 10.10.10.10 │ $250 │
├────────┼───────────┼─────────────┼──────┤
│jack    │ India     │ 10.10.10.12 │ $190 │
├────────┼───────────┼─────────────┼──────┤
│joy     │ Australia │ 10.10.10.13 │ $230 │
├────────┼───────────┼─────────────┼──────┤
│christ  │ canada    │ 10.10.10.15 │ $190 │
├────────┼───────────┼─────────────┼──────┤
│jackson │ africa    │ 10.10.10.20 │ $230 │
└────────┴───────────┴─────────────┴──────┘
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the `column` command:

```
column -t file
Name     country    IP           Cost
sam      us         10.10.10.10  $250
jack     India      10.10.10.12  $190
joy      Australia  10.10.10.13  $230
christ   canada     10.10.10.15  $190
jackson  africa     10.10.10.20  $230
```